# How to avoid constant switching to and from English keyboard layout to type Vim commands when writing in non-Latin language (e.g., Greek)?

Tags: vim, keymapping

I am giving Vim a serious try for coding my Python apps.
However, Vim is proving to be so flexible, I was thinking to use it as my main editor at work for writing lawyer/legal documents. The problem is that my mother tongue is not English but Greek. So, I have mapped <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> to change between English and Greek keyboard layouts.

The issue I am experiencing is that I have to press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> each time I want to enter a Vim command (to return back to English). So it is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> when I type my document, then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> again to enter Vim commands. This defeats the purpose of using Vim, at least in terms of speed of use.

So my question is simple: Is there any way to avoid those frequent <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> keyboard layout changes just for entering Vim commands when writing in a non-Latin language (e.g., Greek)?

Comment: [Here's a simple way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10983604/)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

This problem can be solved with the help of the `keymap` option.
It allows to define an alternate keyboard mapping to use in modes
requiring text input.

To switch between the default and alternate keymaps while in Insert,
Replace, or Command-line mode (but not Normal mode), use
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>^</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>).
Changing the keymap affects text input only; keyboard behavior in
Normal mode stays the same regardless of the current keymap setting.
One can leave Insert mode writing in Greek and immediately use
Normal-mode keybindings without switching to a different keyboard
layout. If one then returns to Insert mode or, for example, starts
a search by typing `/`, Vim switches the keymap back to Greek
automatically.

The current keymap used in those text-entering modes is remembered
between switchings to other modes. The only exception from this
behaviour is made for Command-line mode which always starts with the
default keymap, since most of the time it is required to type an Ex
command (in ASCII). With the `keymap` option set, user is supposed
to work in Vim keeping system keyboard layout set to English while
switching Vim keymap with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>^</kbd> (instead of
the system-wide layout switch).

To enable, say, the UTF-8 Greek keymap permanently, add the following
line to your `.vimrc` file.

```
:set keymap=greek_utf-8
```

There are many predefined keymaps for a large set of languages, you
can browse them all in Vim itself using `:e $VIMRUNTIME/keymap`. Note
that usually there are several keymaps provided for one language which
differ only by character encoding, so that anybody could choose one
that suits their configuration.

I also recommend setting the options below to specify whether the
keymap should be enabled by default in Insert mode and when entering
a search pattern:

```
:set iminsert=0 imsearch=-1
```

See `:help iminsert` and `:help imsearch` for the detailed explanation.

There is also a special language mode that, if I am not mistaken,
was introduced in Vim earlier than `keymap`. It allows to achieve
the behaviour similar to the one provided by `keymap` through manually
specifying letter pairs that correspond to the keys on keyboard in
a long string to be saved in the `langmap` option. Personally—my
native language is not English, too—I prefer (and recommend) using
the `keymap` way instead.

In conclusion, I should emphasize that all of the above is equally
applicable to any other language Vim has (or can be configured to
have) a keymap for.

See also [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8152137/254635) to a similar question ‘[Vim “annoyance”
with keyboard layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8015231/254635)’ that has been asked since I originally
gave this answer.

Comment: You are amazing!!! Your suggestion did not work, but you pointed me to the correct direction. All I had to do was to change set keymap=greek_utf-8 to set keymap = greek_iso-8859-7 . For a stange reason greek utf displays weird characters, the same happens with my firefox when it chooses utf, but iso also work there. Everything else worked like a charm I just press ctrl+^ in edit mode as you suggested and I can change between greek and englis while the command interface remains in english . You are a life savior , thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to use something else than ctrl+^. It's difficult to press Ctrl+Shift+6.

Comment: @Sergey:  `Ctrl+6` works as well.  If it's still uncomfortable for you to type, create an easy to use mapping.  For example, to remap it to `Ctrl+L` use `inoremap <c-l> <c-^>`.

Comment: Ctrl + ^ just opens up a new file in the buffer for me; does not switch languages.

Comment: @dionyziz:  That is because `Ctrl`+`^` switches to the alternate buffer in Normal mode; while in Insert and Command-line modes it toggles language mappings.  Compare `:help ^^` with `:help i_^^` and `:help c_^^`.

Comment: @Kilon perhaps your terminal font does not support UTF-8?

Comment: @ib Thanks for `inoremap <c-l> <c-^>`! Was searching for how to remap this. Mapping to `<F3>` works best.