# How to resolve the annoyance with switching keyboard layouts for different languages in Vim?

Tags: vim, windows-xp

Here’s the thing. I have two keyboard layouts, ‘HR’ (Croatian, my native language) and ‘EN’ (English). Well, actually I have some more but they’re not important at the moment.

When working with Vim, I often have to switch to ‘EN’—since on ‘HR’ I don't have neither `[`,`]`, nor `{`,`}`, nor a lot of other characters—and then switch back to ‘HR’ for my own language characters. This is a pain.

Of course, since I’m working without a taskbar, this often results in wasted
<kbd>Shift</kbd> key presses.

**Is there a way within Vim to “detect” a keyboard layout set, evaluate it, and put it in status line?**

I’ve tried remapping some keys (like tilda to backtick) but that just introduced a whole new lot of problems.

All advice on this (not thought of here) will be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps better on http://superuser.com/.

Comment: Am I right in concluding that you always want to switch to EN keyboard mode for vim? In that case, I'd phrase the question as such. That is likely possible

Comment: Similar problem here, except with three keyboard layouts. It would be nice to have Vim switch to qwerty for modes other than the insertion.

Comment: @nightcracker - Unless something changed in the last few days, Vim questions are ontopic on SO.

Comment: @sehe - Not necessarily. What Don Reba is suggesting would be better.

Comment: @DonReba - Excellent suggestion. I didn't think of it, but you're right - that would be the best way to go.

Comment: @Idigas: I'd search the [vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Vim_Tips_Wiki) and [script libraries](http://www.vim.org/scripts/index.php) for the plugins that do `dvorak` and `simplified chinese` and stuff like that. I imagine they all share the same challenge, and I'm sure I've seen both

Comment: @sehe - I've tried finding something alike before posting this. If you think you have a potential working solution, don't hesistate to post it as an answer.

Comment: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776728/using-vim-with-the-greek-language/3777557#3777557) to a similar question "[Using Vim with the Greek language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776728/using-vim-with-the-greek-language)".  Cc: @sehe

Comment: @ib.: nice work that. I +1-ed it!

Comment: @ ldigas: would you post your resolution as a self-answer so it can be found by future SO searchers? Don't forget to credit (+1) the answers you used, and I'll be happy to +1 if it adds value for future searchers

Comment: @ldigas:  If the solution I referenced is applicable for your question, I could adapt it and post as an answer for this question.

Comment: @ib. - Yes, do that and I'll accept ti.

Comment: I have written the answer presenting all of the key options (pun intended) concerning keymap configuration.  Additionally, I will probably add a few more details about X Input Method later.  Cc: @sehe

Comment: @ib. you're being almost too nice :) Thanks for the nudge, will read later

Comment: @ib - Sorry ib. mate, I completely "lost" track of this one. I don't know what I did at the time of this question, but recall that your answer helped somehow. In anycase I'll accept it for now, and try to find what I did at the time that solved the problem, when I find a free hour or two these days.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is a systematic way of language-related key remapping in Vim
that resides in configuring a whole range of mappings at once by
setting the `keymap` option. It allows to define a mapping between
characters of English keyboard layout and corresponding non-English
characters for that layout (see `:help mbyte-keymap`). The translation
takes place only in situations where the user typing is interpreted
as text input, not as invocation of a Vim command of any kind. This
applies to Insert, Replace, and Command-line modes, as well as to
entering a search pattern or a single-character argument for the
`f`, `t`, `r` commands and alike.

In all of the aforementioned contexts, except for a pending character
argument, toggling the use of a key mapping specified in the `keymap`
option is performed by the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>^</kbd>
(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>) keystroke. (See `:help i_^^` and
`:help c_^^`.) As it is mentioned above, enabled keymap affects only
text input; keyboard behavior in Normal mode remains the same
regardless of the current language mapping. This way, when one leaves
Insert mode writing in non-English keymap, they can immediately use
Normal mode commands and keybindings without switching keyboard
layout. Returning back to Insert mode switches input to the keymap
used the last time it has been left (the fact that keymap was active
is stored in the `iminsert` option).

However, the state of the key mapping is not remembered for
Command-line mode by default, since it is considered convenient to
start typing in English every time, as the names of Ex commands are
all in ASCII. To negate that behavior, use the command

```
:set imcmdline
```

Whether the language mappings are active when typing a search pattern
(for the `/` and `?` commands) is remembered separately, via the
`imsearch` option. To synchronize toggling the use of the language
mappings for entering a search pattern and inserting text in a buffer,
set the option accordingly:

```
:set imsearch=-1
```

There are not a few predefined keymaps for about a dozen and a half
languages. Usually, a language is supported by several mappings that
differ by encoding or keyboard layout they are designed to be used
with. One can browse them all in Vim itself with `:e $VIMRUNTIME/keymap`.
In order to enable a particular keyboard mapping, set the `keymap`
option to the name of that mapping. For instance, the following
command changes `keymap` to the built-in UTF-8 Croatian mapping.

```
:set keymap=croatian_utf-8
```

If you want to customize an existing keymap or to create a brand new
one, look into the keymap file format at `:help keymap-file-format`.

Putting the above command into the `.vimrc` file lets you activate the
specified keymap in all buffers. Nevertheless, the `keymap` option is
even more powerful since it is local to buffer, meaning that various
keyboard mappings could be used simultaneously in different buffers
depending on settings (which can be affected by file types through
the use of autocommands).

Comment: `imcmdline` does not work with 'lnoremap', which is used internally by `'keymap'`. It does work with `IM` (Input Method) instead.