# How do you use vim for programming with a Spanish keyboard?

Tags: vim, keyboard

I'm starting the journey to learn and effectively use vim with a **Spanish keyboard**.

I've faced the first important question:

> If you are used to a non-US keymap, what is better, to remap the vim movement keys or to switch layouts every time you do programming?

By now, I think remapping vim movement keys to accommodate my usual finger positions is the way to go. I'd like to know what other spanish guys do.

In general, it would be of great use to know if there are any other caveats or tricks important for Spanish vim users.

Comment: I would ask to your near colleagues, or to other spanish Linux users. I feel your question is too localized.

Comment: Possible duplicate of "[Vim "annoyance" with keyboard layouts](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8015231/254635)".  See also previous answer to very similar question, "[Using Vim with the Greek language](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3776728/254635)".

Comment: Nowadays laptops with Spanish keyboard are being sold even in the US. I wouldn't say that this question is only relevant to a small geographic area.

Comment: After rereading the two possible duplicates, I agree.  Those questions  probably offer good information for the OP but don't necessarily answer this question.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch English : 360 million native speakers, 54 countries; Spanish : 405 million, 21 countries. No so localized imho. Compare with German : 98 million or French : 72 million native speakers.

Comment: @joaquin But how many of them have access to the technology you and I are working with? It's sad, but there is a reason Spanish Wikipedia has actually less articles than German and French Wikipedias.

Answer (score 1):

Goran, I use a spanish keyboard with a US mapping. However, using whichever mapping, the vim movement keys are the same.