# How to automatically change keyboard layout on switch to vim normal-mode?

Tags: vim, keyboard-layout

Sometimes I use vim to write non-US text, and when I wanna use any command in normal mode, I need to change layout to US. It's possible to do that automatically?

PS. I can do mapping like [this](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3885), but in this case command looks like :ц instead :w - not pretty and typo-risk.

**Update**

I don't want to use keymap option, because I prefer switch languages by CapsLock.
I've try to write autocmd for InsertLeave event, but failed...

**Update 2**

Probably anybody know, why the following not work?

```
function SetUsLayout()
  !setxkbmap us,ru
endfunction

autocmd InsertLeave * call SetUsLayout()
```

Comment: The answer here is relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3777557/329063

Comment: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8152137/254635) to a similar question "[Vim “annoyance” with keyboard layouts](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8015231/254635)" rather than the one linked in the previous comment, since it covers effectively the same issue and it is more thorough.

Comment: I already write in Update, that don't want to use keymap option, because it's not possible to map CapsLock in vim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like, that cross-platform solution doesn't exist... So, under KDE I use the following:

```
function! SetUsLayout()
  silent !qdbus org.kde.keyboard /Layouts setLayout us > /dev/null
endfunction

autocmd InsertLeave * call SetUsLayout()
```

Answer (score 5):

```
:help langmap
```

is likely to provide all the info you need.

Comment: "Characters entered in Command-line mode will NOT be affected by this option." So hjkl works fine, but commands not.

Comment: This deals with what you asked for: normal mode commands. See `:help keymap` for the command mode.

Comment: Ok, I can set keymap=russian-jcukenwin, but to switch to US I need to use ctrl+^ (or map any other), but not very convenient CapsLock.

Comment: I'm not really in a position to test it out (french layout) but you could try something like `:nnoremap : :<C-^>`. What's the deal with CapsLock?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2176558/656610

At now I try to use OS-dependent solution: setxkbmap to switch layout automaticly on InsertLeave event

Comment: This approach is limited in that some keyboard layouts, for example the Canadian Multilingual layout, map keys not to characters but to the first keystroke of a digraph.  For example, the key which in the US Standard layout produces `[` will, when pressed with the Canadian Multilingual Layout active, initiate the creation of a circumflex-accented character, e.g. `ê`.

Answer (score 1):

For me, using qdbus is the best option. I've made a simple but fragile plugin that works really well for me: https://github.com/ironhouzi/bikey-vim/tree/master/plugin

I call it fragile, since it doesn't have much robustness to it if anybody else wants to use it.

I mostly want English when I'm using Vim, with a few exceptions. When I want to write in my native language, I hit 'leader'-k and my airline status bar will show that I've switched language. When the language is not English, the script will ensure that every time I enter insert mode, my native language is set through qdbus. Every time I leave insert mode, the language is set back to English. It also supports individual settings between buffers. Even though this might not be the best way to do things, I thought I'd share it, in case someone else might get some use out of it.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu I use the following:

```
function! SetUsLayout()
  silent !qdbus org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Keyboard /org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/Keyboard org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Keyboard.SetInputSource 0 > /dev/null
endfunction

autocmd InsertLeave * call SetUsLayout()
```

or shorter:

```
silent !gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current 0
```

Answer (score 0):

*In **Linux with X11** you can do the following for nvim\vim:*

```lua
SetUsLayout = function()
  vim.api.nvim_command('silent !xkb-switch -s us')
end

vim.api.nvim_command('autocmd InsertLeave * call SetUsLayout()')
```

([Here's an extended use case senario](https://github.com/GiorgosXou/our-neovim-setup/blob/f8a03e8dd02cf2fcf8297df62056ad2d8588acb7/init.lua#L41-L48))